# Pandas: Generate a timeseries filled with the last day of the year

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

Say I have a Pandas timeseries with irregular intervals.

```
2010-01-04   88.82 
2010-11-29   90.70 
2010-12-01   90.09  
2011-02-26   90.10 
2011-08-01   90.55  
2011-09-21   89.50  
2012-04-01   89.06 
2012-04-30   90.22  
2012-05-03   90.21
```

I would like to create from the index another timeseries where the column is populated by the last date of the year. So for 2010 dates, it will show 2010-12-01 and for 2011 dates, it will show 2011-09-21, etc. The desired output is

```
2010-01-04   2010-12-01
2010-11-29   2010-12-01
2010-12-01   2010-12-01 
2011-02-26   2011-09-21
2011-08-01   2011-09-21 
2011-09-21   2011-09-21  
2012-04-01   2012-05-03
2012-04-30   2012-05-03 
2012-05-03   2012-05-03
```

I can extract out the index and group them by year.

```
end_dates=[]
df_idx = df.index
year_df = df_idx.groupby(df_idx.year)
for yr in year_df.keys():
    end_dates.append(max(year_df[yr]))
```

This gives me a list of yearly end dates. But how do I associate these end dates back to the original index to arrive at the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your index is a datetimeindex object.

If you have pandas series you can use this:

```
s.to_frame().assign(end_dates=s.groupby(s.index.year).transform(lambda x: x.index.max()))
```

or if you already have a dataframe:

```
df.assign(end_dates=df.groupby(df.index.year)['A'].transform(lambda x: x.index.max()))
```

Output:

```
                1  end_dates
0                           
2010-01-04  88.82 2010-12-01
2010-11-29  90.70 2010-12-01
2010-12-01  90.09 2010-12-01
2011-02-26  90.10 2011-09-21
2011-08-01  90.55 2011-09-21
2011-09-21  89.50 2011-09-21
2012-04-01  89.06 2012-05-03
2012-04-30  90.22 2012-05-03
2012-05-03  90.21 2012-05-03
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am getting this error from the assign function. ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1. My original dataframe is actually two columns so I had to modify your code to extract a column and turn it back into a dataframe before assigning, i.e. df.assign(end_dates=df.iloc[:,0].to_frame().groupby(df.index.year).transform(lambda x: x.index.max()))

Comment: Is your date in the index, if not you can set_index then run the second statement. and reset_index afterwards.

Comment: Yes, the date is in the index. I don't quite understand what you have in mind if the date is not the index. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What happens when you run the second statement as is?

Comment: It gives the following error for assign. ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1.

Comment: If I run what's in the parenthesis, end_dates=df.groupby(df.index.year).transform(lambda x: x.index.max(), it will show a dataframe with two columns plus the datetime Index.

Comment: That's why I extracted out the first column with df.iloc[:,0] and converted back into a dataframe.

Comment: Sorry.. at home, just put the kids down for nap.  Okay, what you need to do is to specify a column after the groupby part.  You see in my edited answer, where I have ['A'] just choose any column it doesn't matter.